# "Live" byte source interface?

Tags: java, android, serial-port

I'm facing what I would expect to be a common problem, but I haven't been able to find an existing solution.  I want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel before I roll my own.

Some time ago, I wrote a Bluetooth serial library in which a worker thread establishes the socket connection and then reads from it, posting callbacks in the UI thread whenever data is received.  My rationale is that you typically want to do I/O (especially blocking I/O) outside the UI thread, so why not let the library take care of it?  The app just needs to implement the callback interface to handle incoming data.  Something like this:

```
public interface ConnectorListener {
   void onData(BluetoothConnector connector, byte[] data);
}
```

Now I want to generalize my interfaces to handle other serial byte sources and sinks.  So once again, I'm casting around to see if there's an existing interface that I could use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing I've found is [AsynchronousByteChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousByteChannel.html).  With this interface, you initiate a read and get a callback to your `CompletionHandler` when data arrives.  This is slightly different from my original idea of a "live source" that would read constantly, making multiple callbacks.

Anyway, it's moot because `AsynchronousByteChannel` was added in Java 1.7 and is not available on Android.  I might copy it to make standardizing my code easier in the event it does become available.